# Is it possible to place ruby fonts on the bottom?

Tags: css

Using CSS would I be able to move the line in the  tags to the bottom of the word instead of the top of the word?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      rt {
        line-height: Normal;
        font-size: .4em;
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

  <ruby>
  中文 <rt>Zhōngwén</rt>
  </ruby>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would wrap your Zhōngwén in `<rb></rb>` and make it the base of the ruby container.  Then have the 中文 wrapped in the `<rt></rt>` tags and style each. Take a look at what I did here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      rb {
        line-height: Normal;
        font-size: .4em;
        text-align: center;
      }
      rt{
        font-size: 16px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

  <ruby>
  <rb>Zhōngwén</rb> <rt>中文</rt>
  </ruby>
```

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/rb, ```rb``` is deprecated. According to https://www.w3.org/International/articles/ruby/styling.en.html, you can use ```ruby { ruby-position: under; }```